# Responsive icon does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a site for a friend.

Unfortunately, I am new to responsive development, and to CSS in general.
I tried to implement the code from W3Schools.com on my grid site (which also something new for me), but it didn't work out.

Here is link from W3Schools.com:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

I would like to have an icon in the center next to current menu page.

Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "header") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "header";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*grid and rows adjustments*/

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2.5fr 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 0.5fr 1fr 20px;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
}

.header {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.content-1 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.content-2 {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}


/*.content-3 {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}*/

.footer {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.header ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.header ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.header ul li a.active {
  background-color: #C1CFD0;
  color: white;
}

.header ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.header .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* OTHER STYLES */

.item {
  background-color: #C1CFD0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #C1CFD0 0%, #C1CFD0 85%, #C1CFD0 100%);
  /*box-shadow: 0 10px 20px;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  background-color: #909fa0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #C1CFD0;
  , #909fa0);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #909fa0;
}

.sidebar img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content-1,
.content-2,
.content-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #9FC4D2, #E4E3DE);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.content-1 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-1 h1 {
  animation-name: h1animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.content-1 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-name: h1animation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.content-2>p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: h1animation;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes h1animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*responsive version of the site*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar {
    background-image: url("../img/contact1a.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 0.5fr 1fr 20px;
    grid-gap: 0px;
  }
  .content-1 {
    background-image: url("../img/violinead.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .header .icon {
    display: block;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item header" id="myTopnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item sidebar">
      <img src="img/contact1.jpg" alt="contact1">
    </div>
    <div class="item content-1">
      <h1><br><br><br>André Rothweiler</h1>
      <h2>Web-designer</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item content-2">
      <p>I’m an enthusiastic web-developer currently working as a freelancer in Zurich, Switzerland. I love to learn new things and create them! Just take a look on this side, to find out more about me! </p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="item content-3">Content-3</div> -->
    <div class="item footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope you can help me!

Friendly regards.

Comment: Just as a side note, w3schools is really not a very good resource and is often quite incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I do agree, but it helps a lot also.

Comment: That's fair, just would recommend taking it with a pinch of salt :) There's a wealth of better responsive CSS tutorials via Google

Comment: true but responsive is so hard, I wish it was 1998 lol But I see a mistake in a code, indeed you a right, it has a mistake but I can't fix it...

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial on W3C adds and removes the class "responsive" when clicking on the icon. You don't have any CSS for that class, so it can not have any effect.

Comment: This is probably better as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: thanks for the hint. i just saw that I can not post comments yet. Next time I will know better.

Comment: Yeah it's an annoying "feature" of stack overflow, but there's also a reason for it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: These kind of answers usually get deleted during the review process too, so normally you gain very little from it, which is a shame when your point is definitely valid.